# Convert object to byte array (to send it through a socket). then convert it back

Tags: android, serialization, parcelable

I have the following class definition:

```
public class Message {
     private String sender, text;

     public Message(String sender, String text) {
         this.sender = sender;
         this.text = text;
     }

}
```

I would like to be able to send an instance of this Message class over a bluetooth socket. In order to do this, it will need to be converted into a byte[]. After it has been sent, I need to convert it back to a Message object (on the other side of the socket). How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two possible answers
  Serializable vs Parcelable

Serializable relatively easy to implement but not efficient in term of memory and CPU

http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/Serializable.html

Parcelable more complex to implement but more efficient in term of memory and CPU

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html

Answer (score 0):

Look into serialization.

http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/Serializable.html

Answer (score 0):

You could define a function, which returns a `byte[]` and just call it before you send it per bluetooth. The byte-array could be like `{ sendersize, textsize, sender, text }`. Define also a function which reverts the process and call it on the other side.